# Removing an OverylayItem from Map

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to allow a User to remove a point (or more specifically, an OverlayItem) from a map. I followed the developer [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) to get started and implemented the CustomMapView in [this](http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2011/android-handling-longpresslongclick-on-map-revisited/) tutorial to capture a long press on the map.

So now I have a program which allows a User to place points on the map. My next goal is to let the User remove points. Here is my code for when a User clicks an existing point on the map.

```
public class OurItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

//Create new list of points
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mapContext;
@Override
protected boolean onTap(final int index) {
    Button edit, remove;

    //Get index of item tapped
    OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

    //Create Dialog to show point info, allow for edit or removal.
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mapContext);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mapContext);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mapContext);
    builder.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    builder.setMessage(item.getSnippet());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_or_edit_location_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view); 
    builder.show();

    //BUTTONS

    edit = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    remove = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    //Edit Button Listener
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    //Remove Button Listener
    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            removeOverlay(index); <--------

            Log.d("View location info", "user clicked delete.");
            return;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Here is my code for removeOverlay.

```
protected void removeOverlay(int index) {

    mapOverlays.remove(index);
    com.example.mapproject.MainActivity.mapView.invalidate();
}
```

After I click on an existing point a dialog is presented offering to remove the point. When I have selected to remove the point, the point still remains on the screen. If I place a new point, the 'deleted' one is removed. However, if I click the 'deleted' point or another existing point, the program crashes with this error.

[image: error]

If you have a clue of what to do, I'd appreciate to hear from you !!

**Edit**

Following a tip from Vishwa Patel, I remove a point from the map straight away using postInvalidate(). However, I still get indexoutofbounds exceptions when I click where the icon was..

Comment: Instead `com.example.mapproject.MainActivity.mapView.invalidate();` try with `v.invalidate ()` in `onClick(View v)....`

Comment: Do you have to call `populate()` again? Basically the ItemizedOverlay is meant to do a lot of precaching up front. If you update the data set, there has to be a way for it to redo all the caches. Populate is called when you first create this structure. If it isn't allowed to be called multiple times on the same object you could do a few things. Make a new state for the drawable and just inactivate it (invisible, and ignore hits), or you could recreate the entire ItemizedOverlay and add it in the MapView overlays collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the solution [here](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/android-itemizedoverlay-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-nullpointerexception-workarounds/). It seems to work so far, the answer was to put the following line into my removeOverlay method,

```
setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
```

The code to remove an OverylayItem from my custom Overlay is,

```
    protected void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlayItem) {

    mapOverlays.remove(overlayItem);
    MainActivity.mapOverlays.remove(this);
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    populate();

}
```

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to call `invalidate()` on your `MapView`, forcing it to re-draw itself.  As the commenters mentioned, you may also need to re-call `populate()`.  Your app is probably crashing because it's trying to call `onTap()` for an `OverlayItem` that doesn't exist.  You may also want to try any method that could "refresh" the `MapView` and/or Overlay, because that is what you need to do to make the `OverlayItem` disappear.

Comment: I tried those methods, they helped remove the icon, but if I clicked where the icon had been, I would get an array out of bounds error, I found a page documenting a similar issue which seemed to fix it! http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/android-itemizedoverlay-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-nullpointerexception-workarounds/

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution!  Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
com.example.mapproject.MainActivity.mapView.postInvalidate();
```

since you are making an invalidate call from a non-UI thread, as specified in the documentation for postInvalidate();

Comment: Hey, This worked a treat for getting rid of the icons straight away ! However, there are still a couple of issues.. If you click where the icon was, the app will crash with an indexoutofbounds exception..

Comment: @Tomcelic to solve that issue I think you will need to also remove the Overlay from the List<Overlay> mapOverlays that exists in your MapActivity class (I assume since you are following the official developer tutorial the class should be called HelloGoogleMaps). So, you will have to make that list static and remove this particular overlay from that list (you can do this by just saying HelloGoogleMaps.mapOverlays.remove(this); that should do the trick).

Comment: Nope that didn't seem to do it either :(

Comment: I think I found the solution! Seems to work so far, let me know what you think, http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/android-itemizedoverlay-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-nullpointerexception-workarounds/

Comment: @Tomcelic That's great! Yea, the article you linked to makes sense.